# select item with bigger value of cumulated sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `subdata`:

```
PageId  VolumePred  ConversionPred  OSBrowser
1005581 8.0               7.0       (11, 16)
1016529 175.0            85.0       (11, 16)
1016529 4.0               4.0       (11, 16)
1016529 4.0               4.0       (12, 14)
1016529 29.0             19.0       (12, 16)
```

I try to select only the `PageId` that the cumulated sum of `VolumePred` <450. We should select at first `pageId` that has the bigger value of `ConversionPred`.

For this, I started to sort the dataframe by `ConversionPred`:

```
subdata.groupby('OSBrowser')
subdata.sort_values(by='ConversionPred', ascending=False)
```

Then, I calculated the sum of `ConversionPred` and `VolumePred` for each group of OSBrowser:

```
h=subdata.groupby(['PageId', 'OSBrowser'])[['ConversionPred', 'VolumePred']].agg('sum')
```

Then:

```
h=h.sort_values(['ConversionPred'],ascending=False).groupby('OSBrowser')
df = h[h['VolumePred'].cumsum() < 450]
```

But I got this error :

> KeyError: 'Columns not found: False, True

The expected output :

```
PageId  VolumePred  ConversionPred  OSBrowser
1005581 8.0               7.0       (11, 16)
1016529 179.0            89.0       (11, 16)
1016529 4.0               4.0       (12, 14)
1016529 29.0             19.0       (12, 16)
```

So we at first select this:

```
1016529 179.0            89.0       (11, 16)
```

Then:

```
1005581 8.0               7.0       (11, 16)
```

because the sum of volume : 179+8 is less than 450, so they will be selected

Comment: try `df.loc[h['VolumePred'].cumsum() < 450, :]`

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer df is unfound..

Comment: "We should select at first pageId that has the bigger value of ConversionPred." What do you mean by this? What is your expected output?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I meant `h.loc[h['VolumePred'].cumsum() < 450, :]`

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer i get this error : 
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: Also where are cumulating the sum? It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @not_speshal I try to select for each group of (OSBrowser) the page_id that has the bigger value of Conversion with the constraint : that the sum of cumulated volume for each group of OSBrowser is less than 450

Comment: Can you please post your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try:

```
h = subdata.groupby(["PageId", "OSBrowser"]).sum().reset_index().sort_values(["OSBrowser","ConversionPred"],ascending=[True,False])
output = h[h.groupby("OSBrowser")["VolumePred"].transform("cumsum").lt(450)].reset_index(drop=True)

>>> output
    PageId OSBrowser  VolumePred  ConversionPred
0  1016529  (11, 16)       179.0            89.0
1  1005581  (11, 16)         8.0             7.0
2  1016529  (12, 14)         4.0             4.0
3  1016529  (12, 16)        29.0            19.0
```